# Coffeescript functions are not working in Rails app at all

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm stumped here...I want to add a small and minor CSS/JS detail to my app. I have an app where users can create many posts. I am trying to add the function where once a user hovers over the posts, the posts should trigger a nice background color. I've checked everything and I don't see what I am doing wrong.

I've set up a `post.js.coffee` file under my stylesheet directory. I've also added the css styling in my `application.scss` file. My `application.js` file is wired up to require some JS and in my views folder under my posts folder, I am iterating through `@post` in my index template which is where I want to activate the hover background trigger. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Gemfile -

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.0'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '= 3.0.1'
gem 'font-icons-rails', :git=> 'git://github.com/shorelabs/font-icons-rails.git'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

post index.html.erb file -

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h2>Welcome<small> - <%= current_user.username %>, start posting!</small></h2>
</div>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div id="posts_feed">
      <h3><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post)%></h3>
      <h4><%= post.description %></h4>

      <div id="votes">
        <%= link_to '', vote_post_path(post, vote: true), method: 'post', remote: true, class: "icon-fa-arrow-up" %>
        <span id="post_<%=post.id%>_votes"><%= post.total_votes %></span>
        <%= link_to '', vote_post_path(post, vote: false), method: 'post', remote: true, class: "icon-fa-arrow-down" %>
      </div>

      <small class="muted">
        <% if post.comments.count.to_s == "1" %>
          <%= post.comments.count %> <%= link_to "comment", post %>
        <% else %>
          <%= post.comments.count %> <%= link_to "comments", post %>
        <% end %>
        | posted by <%= link_to post.creator.username %> <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) + ' ago' %>
        <% if logged_in? && (post.creator == current_user) %> |
          <%= link_to "edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
          | <i class="icon-fa-user"></i>
        <% end %>
      </small>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

application.js file -

```
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

posts.js.coffee -

```
$ ->
  $('.post').hover (event) ->
    $(this).toggleClass("hover")
```

application.scss -

```
 .post.hover {
  background: red;
 }
```

Comment: I don't see any .post CSS class in your post index file. If this is the case your Js won't get triggered. Try adding a .post class to the #post_feed div. e.g <div class="post" id="post_feed">. Also consider adding the post.id to the post_feed id so it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to use coffescript for a hover state? Why not just use CSS?

```
.post:hover {
background: red;}
```

Comment: Actually the reason being is that I plan on adding a few other links and things that will only be visible to post creators and things like that. That css hover state should work like you mentioned but even testing that out returns nothing...hmmmm. Something bigger here is definitely wrong but I can't point it out yet...thanks for the response though.